# Authorize dialog is not requesting publish_actions or publish_stream permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have publish_actions as a user permission for my app and publish_stream as an extended permission but neither are being requested when the a user grants access to Facebook.

I found an article the mentioned I have to turn on "enhanced auth dialog" but it was an old article and the option doesn't seem to exist any longer.

I do have a story and collection setup in the object graph but that didn't seem to change anything.  Any suggestions?

Comment: When using `FB.login`, you have to pass the permissions you want to ask for in the `scope` parameter – have you done that? (Settings in the app dashboard affect automatically triggered login from the app center only.)

Comment: nope, sure haven't.  Thanks, that was driving me crazy.  For some reason I totally forgot about having to set the scope parameter the last time I did something list this. 

Thanks for the help!